# Heap sort or quick sort better one?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I gave a written round of a company.
I have a doubt in a question can anyone help me?

> which is the fastest sorting algorithm among the following?
>   a - bubble sort
>   b - shell sort
>   c - heap sort
>   d - quick sort

I'm confused b/w quick sort and heap sort both have a time complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: That's a really badly phrased question. The answer depends on what exactly does “fast” mean and it could also depend on the data.

Comment: fast means i think in terms of time complexity for a larger n

Comment: That was never specified.  For smaller N, it could be more efficient in terms of space and time to use bubblesort.

Comment: @akash But that's not clear from the question at all. And asymptotic time complexity is still not specific enough: it could mean average case complexity or worst case complexity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is each sorting algorithm used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933759/when-is-each-sorting-algorithm-used), as well as [quicksort-vs-heapsort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467751/quicksort-vs-heapsort?lq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no "fastest" sorting algorithm.

Theoretical performance of an algorithm always depends on the input data. In their respective *worst cases*, Heap sort is faster than Quick sort. In average case, Quick sort is faster. It is probably possible to concoct a custom-tailored *best case* for each algorithm to make it outperform all the others.

That is actually the reason such "hybrid" algorithms as *[Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)* exist: Introsort begins with Quick sort and switches to Heap sort if it sees that Quick sort is struggling with this specific input.

On top of that the real-life performance of any algorithm can be significantly affected by how well it works on a specific hardware platform. A theoretically "fast" algorithm can lose miserably to a primitive and "slow" one, if the latter is in better "sync" with the properties of the hardware.

Comment: Exactly, the question would be hard to answer even if it was specified properly, which it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

See [Wikipedia: Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

> Heapsort: Although somewhat slower in practice on most machines than a well-implemented quicksort, it has the advantage of a more favorable worst-case O(n log n) runtime

Answer (score 2):

In the average case: Quick-Sort, since the constant of its O(nlgn) running time is better.

In the worst case: Heap-Sort, since in the worst case, the running time of Quick-Sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>).