# Sorting a list with a function to return a new list

Tags: python

I'm having trouble sorting through a list without using the built-in sorted() function. I've done my research but I can't seem to find a solution.

Here's what I have:

```
def min_len_word(list):
    return min(list, key=len)
```

I want to use this function to return a list that is sorted by the length of its elements and to do that I think I should use for or while loop but I'm uncertain of how to use a function within a loop.

edit

My apologies for lack of information!
I have two functions

```
def min_len_word(list):
return min(list, key=len)
```

and

```
def sorted_list(list):
```

I want the second function to use the first function to get the result

Comment: How is `min` sorting anything? `min` returns, as the name suggests, the smallest element in the collection.

Comment: You have many sorting algorithms. Use them!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think he wants to use that function in another sorting function. But it isn't really clear.

Comment: "I've done my research" <- I don't believe you. How can you *not* find a fistful of search algorithms with a trivial google search?

Comment: I edited my post. I was not looking for an algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is each sorting algorithm used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933759/when-is-each-sorting-algorithm-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure what you really want to do, here is an example, how you can sort list of dicts in python:

```
x = [ 
    {'text':"f", 'len':5},
    {'text':"a", 'len':8},
    {'text':"d", 'len':0},
    {'text':"e", 'len':2},
    {'text':"c", 'len':3},
    {'text':"b", 'len':9}
]

def min_len_word(list):
    return sorted(list, key=lambda k: k['len'])
```

this function returns list sorted by its `len` value.

```
listx = [ "x", "aaa","bbb"]
def min_len_word(list):
    return sorted(list, lambda x,y: cmp(len(x), len(y)))
```

or maybe like that?
this function sorts list of strings by its length

edit:

```
listx = [ "x", "aasdasdadaa","bbxxb","aaa","bbb"]
def min_len_word(list):
    return min(list, key=len)

def sorted_list(list):
    result = []
    while len(list) != 0:
        result.append(min_len_word(list))
        list.remove(min_len_word(list))
    return result

print(sorted_list(listx))
```

function without using sort/sorted :)

Comment: Also known as selection sort.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution that I was looking for